# Speeding up row-by-row loop with if-condition in Python

Tags: python, performance, pandas, loops

I have a dataset of 6 milion rows, the columns are: `symbol`, `timeStamp`, `open price` and `close price`. I run the following loop, which takes very long, though being very simple (if `open price` is `nan`, take `close price` from the previous row):

```
for i in range(0,len(price2)):
    print(i)
    if np.isnan(price3.iloc[i,2]):
        price3.iloc[i,2]=price3.iloc[i-1,3]
```

How can I speed this loop up? As far as I know, I can change to `apply()`, but how can I include the if-condition to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the for loop, you can use [`pandas.Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with the shifted Series for the close price.

```
price3['open price'].fillna(price3['close price'].shift(1), inplace=True)
```

This is vectorized and so should be far faster than your for loop.

Note I am assuming that `price2` and `price3` have the same length and you may as well be iterating over `price3` in your loop.